# function in python that return discord user tag on discord user id as input

Tags: python, discord.py

this is the code:-

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot=commands.Bot()
user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625) 
discrim = user.discriminator
```

this is the error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/hacks/PycharmProjects/just testing new stuff/id.py", line 2, in <module>
    bot=commands.Bot()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'
```

I can't understand what wrong with the code

Comment: I think it speaks for itself. You need to pass the `command_prefix` argument in the bot constructor, also the code you provided is never gonna work, `bot.get_user` grabs the user from cache, but the cache is empty because you're not running it. Also because you didn't enable any intents

Comment: what is the "command_prefix" here, and what changes should i make in the code

Answer (score 1):

Answering your comment

The `command_prefix` it's the prefix for the commands. To make your code work enable intents, run the bot with the token and get the user in a command or on the `on_ready` event, if you simply want to user from it's ID the preferable option would simply using the discord API.

Enabling intents and setting a prefix

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!", # Change the prefix accordingly
    intents = intents   # The intents we defined above
)
```

Remember to also enable privileged member intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), here's [how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Now getting the user object from an ID

```py
# In an event
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625) 
    discrim = user.discriminator
    # Do something


# In a command
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx): # `!foo` in discord
    user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625) 
    discrim = user.discriminator
```

Running the bot

```py
bot.run("YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

Your whole code should look like this

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!", # Change the prefix accordingly
    intents = intents   # The intents we defined above
)

# In an event
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625) 
    discrim = user.discriminator
    # Do something


# In a command
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx): # `!foo` in discord
    user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625) 
    discrim = user.discriminator


bot.run("YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

Take a look at the [introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) and at the [commands introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a command_prefix to it

```py
from discord.ext import commands
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625) 
discrim = user.discriminator
```

and dont forget to run the bot

```py
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
user = bot.get_user(431677941722906625)
discrim = user.discriminator
bot.run('Your Bots Token Here')
```

and you can get the bot's token from here
https://discord.com/developers/application
click Create Application and go to the Bot section and click create bot and then copy the bot's token and replace Your Bots Token Here With your bots token